# How to read with Pandas txt file with column names in each row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm begginer with Python, and I need to read a txt file where the column name is on each row, the columns are dissordered and not all columns are informed. Are there any way to read this kind of file with Pandas?
This is a example (3 rows):

```
pepe01@mail.com:{ssha}fiy9XI6d:created="1575487257" fwd="" spf_block="" quota="1024mb" full_name="Full Name" mailaccess="envia" mailstatus="cancelled"

pepe02@mail.com:{ssha}Q0H90Rf9:created="1305323967" mailaccess="1" mailstatus="active" admin_access="" quota="" expire="0" full_name="Full Name" pais="CO"

pepe03@mail.com:{ssha}sCPC3HOE:created="1550680636" fwd="" pass_question="" pass_answer="" disabled="Y" mailstatus="cancelled" full_name="Name"
```

Comment: I am not an expert on pandas but looking at your data, it seems you have to clean your data first. Like there is an email and then there are <key>=<value> separated by " " afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` module to parse the file.

For example:

```
import re
import pandas as pd


all_data = []
with open('<YOUR FILE>', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        m = re.search(r'^(.*?):(.*?):', line)
        if not m:
            continue
        data = dict(re.findall(r'([^\s]+)="([^"]+)"', line.split(':', maxsplit=2)[-1]))
        data['mail'] = m.group(1)
        data['password'] = m.group(2)
        all_data.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).fillna('')
print(df)
```

Prints the dataframe:

```
      created   quota  full_name mailaccess mailstatus             mail        password expire pais disabled
0  1575487257  1024mb  Full Name      envia  cancelled  pepe01@mail.com  {ssha}fiy9XI6d                     
1  1305323967          Full Name          1     active  pepe02@mail.com  {ssha}Q0H90Rf9      0   CO         
2  1550680636               Name             cancelled  pepe03@mail.com  {ssha}sCPC3HOE                    Y
```