# Read txt file having data as dictionary with some missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, txt

How to read txt file having data stored in the form of a dictionary. I had seen many questions asked with similar problems but none of them were helping.  The txt file can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12TN5ZRHxJmsbgH--2TBQ5_1BLKbxnxEG/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Provide a smaller sample of the .txt file. I don't really want to download half a Gb file to just have a look.

Comment: Also notable that from a _Computer Security_ perspective downloading a file that size is an unreasonable risk to take.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend just taking a slice of your txt file (maybe 10 rows) and creating a new txt file for us to review. You can also just type out a sample table that looks like your txt file so that we can create our own file to solve your problem.

Comment: A small sample of data has been updated. Kindly check for it.

Answer (score 0):

Review this similar question answered by another user. It may solve what it is that you are trying to do.

[How to read with Pandas txt file with column names in each row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62961933/16166192)

Comment: I had found that question but was not able to understand the answer that's why I asked this question. And I think my situation is different. You can check in the link provided.